# input dialog box blender

Tags: blender, textinput, blender-2.61

How to make a simple entry dialog box (like in the image) in blender and processing the text entered through python.I am unable to find any good tutorial on this.

[image: simple entry box]

Answer (score 13):

For the dialog box the answer from [how to show a message from a blender script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697532/how-to-show-a-message-from-a-blender-script/7743556#7743556) might be a starting point.

But I think a better approach is integrating input into the panel like e.g.
[image: String example]

To do this you have to add a `StringProperty` to your add-on and place it inside your panel (see [Addon Tutorial](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_64_9/info_tutorial_addon.html) for more information). The basic steps are:

```
def draw(self, context) :
    col = self.layout.column(align = True)
    col.prop(context.scene, "my_string_prop")
```

...

```
def register() :
    bpy.types.Scene.my_string_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty \
      (
        name = "My String",
        description = "My description",
        default = "default"
      )
```

...

```
def unregister() :
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_string_prop
```

...

You can access the string by `context.scene.my_string_prop`

There is another mode to integrate input. When you add for example a text to your scene you can change the parameters **after the operator has been called** and see the changes immediately:

[image: Add text object]

Changing *Location* will move the newly created text object at another place. I haven't worked with this but it should be similar to the code above.